# Return a downloaded file with Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to return downloaded files with a flask programme:

```
# code to define title and get link
        try:
            YouTube(link).streams.first().download(filename=title)
            print("Successfully Downloaded")
            return send_from_directory('', filename=title, as_attachment=True), "<h1>Complete</h1>"
        except Exception as e:
            exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
            fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
            print(exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)
            return f"<h1>{e}</h1>"
```

But this always returns `<class 'werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound'> app.py 30`, which from my reseach suggests the file can't be found [here](https://werkzeug-doc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/exceptions.html):

```
exception werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound(description=None, response=None)
404 Not Found
Raise if a resource does not exist and never existed.
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `download()` function saves the file as `filename`+".mp4" but your `send_from_directory` only looks for `filename`.
When testing your `return` did still not download the file for me, because of the `, "<h1>Complete</h1>"`. I removed it and it worked fine.
So try this:

```
return send_from_directory('', filename=title+".mp4", as_attachment=True), "<h1>Complete</h1>"
```